# Adding for-loop elements to a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm writing a code where it fetches some text from a site and then, with a for-loop I take the part of the text of my interest. I can print this text but I would like to know how can I send it to a list for latter use. So far the code I've wrote is this one.

```
import urllib2

keyword = raw_input('keyword: ')

URL = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?sort=score&desc=&compress=no&query=%s&fil=&limit=10&force=no&preview=true&format=fasta" % keyword

filehandle = urllib2.urlopen(URL)

url_text = filehandle.readlines()

for line in url_text:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        print line[line.index(' ') : line.index('OS')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `append`:

```
lines = []
for line in url_text:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        lines.append(line) # or whatever else you wanted to add to the list
        print line[line.index(' ') : line.index('OS')]
```

---

Edit: on a side note, python can for loop directly over a file - as in:

```
url_text = filehandle.readlines()
for line in url_text:
    pass

# can be shortened to:
for line in filehandle:
    pass
```

Comment: That's a nice way to do it but with that won't I append the whole line? I would like to append only the text in that line between the 1st space and 'OS' as given in the last line of command.

Comment: @NunoChicória  yes for my example, but you can append what you like to the list. If you only want to keep what you were previously printing, you could do `lines.append(line[line.index(' ') : line.index('OS')])`